# Android .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently busy with this turotial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

And im stuck at this line:

final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

It cannot resolve symbol "R"

How can i import this symbol?

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project

Answer (score 5):

To import R class simply write:

```
import your_package_name.R;
```

Generally the `R` class automatically gets imported but in case if you have some error in any of your xml file then the R file doesn't get created.

Answer (score 0):

check resources in your project, if you have an error in them, the R class can not be created and show error en java classes